# What does this sentence from a technical text book mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

[image: Taken from 'Digital communication systems by Simon Haykin]

> The minimum distance *d*<sub>min</sub> of a linear block code is the smallest Hamming distance between any pair of codewords.

Which of the following meanings are they implying?

1)You consider any pair of codewords, smallest Hamming distance of that pair is the minimum distance, 'd'.

2)You consider all possible pairs of codewords, find Hamming distance of all pairs, smallest of them is the minimum distance, 'd'.

Comment: I'd guess the latter, but this would likely get a more accurate answer on math.SE.

Comment: Please never post text as graphics. It discriminates against those with visual problems and it is not searchable. In any case I would consider this text is too specialized for this site, and should be posted to a list where there are specialists on information theory.

Comment: @Jimm @ David...O.K.

Comment: #1 doesn't work because you do not consider *any pair* of codewords, because any pair has only one minimum distance. Don't you consider all pairs in the space of the linear block code, for the shortest in the group?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Second one is the meaning they are trying to imply. But I am not getting that meaning from the text book sentence. What do you think? Does the given text book sentence give out the second meaning.

Comment: Yes. In this version of your question, though, Hamming is not defined. Is it a type of distance, like a straight line or shortest while circling around obstacles (so there could be choices)?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Hamming distance is a single value for a pair of objects. There is nothing to select from. But if you consider many pair, you get different values corresponding to each pair. Smalles of them is the 'd'. This is the technical meaning.

Comment: It's clearly the second one.   It's not reasonable to say "take one random number and declare it to be the minimum".  Also there is no "**smallest** hamming distance of that pair", there is only "**the** hamming distance of that pair", so your first option is not a valid interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clearly the second meaning.  (I can't even say that the second one is "implied" as it seems quite explicit to me.)

A more technical or algorithmic definition of the minimum distance might be

> For the set of codewords 1..n, define d<sub>i,j</sub> as the Hamming distance between codewords i and j, where 1 <= i <= n, 1 <= j <= n, i <> j.  Then the minimum distance d<sub>min</sub> is the smallest value in the set d.

A larger d<sub>min</sub> allows your encoding to detect and/or correct more errors during the transmission of your coded message.

Comment: Does the given text book definition fail to convey the correct meaning?

Comment: No, the given definition was a very reasonable one if you have the appropriate knowledge of things like "minimum", "codeword", "linear block code", and "hamming distance".

Comment: I am asking, grammatically, is the given statement convey the intended technical meaning?

Comment: Yes, the given statement adequately conveys the intended technical meaning.